# grequests returning 'None' type even after using exception_handler

Tags: python, grequests

I am using grequests module for making async requests. While testing the following piece of code is showing ANOMALY based on TIMEOUT value:

```
>>> grequests.map((grequests.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/1',timeout=0.6),),exception_handler=exception_handler)
failed:  http://httpbin.org/delay/1 

[<Response [200]>]
>>> grequests.map((grequests.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/1', timeout=0.001),),exception_handler=exception_handler)
failed:  http://httpbin.org/delay/1 

[None]
```

So How is the **value of timeout** affecting the execution of last part of exception_handling?

```
>>> def exception_handler(r,e):
        print('failed: ',r.url,'\n')
        #changing the url just for doing sth
        r.url = 'http://httpbin.org/status/200'
        res = r.send().response 
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is you only changed the `url` of `r`, but you did not change the `timeout` of it. The value of `timeout` is stored in `self.kwargs`.

According to the [defination](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/blob/master/grequests.py#L32):

```
""" Asynchronous request.
    Accept same parameters as ``Session.request`` and some additional:
    :param session: Session which will do request
    :param callback: Callback called on response.
                     Same as passing ``hooks={'response': callback}``
    """
    def __init__(self, method, url, **kwargs):
        #: Request method
        self.method = method
        #: URL to request
        self.url = url
        #: Associated ``Session``
        self.session = kwargs.pop('session', None)
        if self.session is None:
            self.session = Session()

        callback = kwargs.pop('callback', None)
        if callback:
            kwargs['hooks'] = {'response': callback}

        #: The rest arguments for ``Session.request``
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        #: Resulting ``Response``
        self.response = None
```

the value of `timeout` is stored in `self.kwargs`. And it did not change when you changed the `url` value which stored in `self.url` in `exception_handler`.